# Solve a system of equations.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, math-software

I have a system of equations:

\begin{align}
& x_{21} (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{11}}f_{1111})( x_{11}   , x_{21},   y_{11} , y_{21} ) + \frac{y_{21}}{x_{11}^2} (\frac{\partial}{\partial y_{11}}f_{1111})(  x_{11}   , x_{21},   y_{11} , y_{21}  ) \\
& = f_{2111}(x_{11}, x_{21}, y_{11}, y_{21}) + x_{11}^{-1}x_{22} f_{1121}( x_{11}, x_{21}, y_{11}, y_{21} ) - \frac{1}{2} x_{22} y_{21}.
\end{align}

\begin{align}
& x_{21} (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{11}}f_{1121})( x_{11}   , x_{21},   y_{11} , y_{21} ) + \frac{y_{21}}{x_{11}^2} (\frac{\partial}{\partial y_{11}}f_{1121})(  x_{11}   , x_{21},   y_{11} , y_{21}  )  \\
& = f_{2121}(x_{11}, x_{21}, y_{11}, y_{21}).
\end{align}

\begin{align}
& x_{21} (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{11}}f_{ 2121})( x_{11}   , x_{21},   y_{11} , y_{21} ) + \frac{y_{21}}{x_{11}^2} (\frac{\partial}{\partial y_{11}}f_{2121})(  x_{11}   , x_{21},   y_{11} , y_{21}  ) = 0.
\end{align}

\begin{align}
& x_{21} (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{11}}f_{  2111})( x_{11}   , x_{21},   y_{11} , y_{21} ) + \frac{y_{21}}{x_{11}^2} (\frac{\partial}{\partial y_{11}}f_{2111})(  x_{11}   , x_{21},   y_{11} , y_{21}  ) \\
& = \frac{1}{2x_{11}} x_{21} x_{22} y_{21} + \frac{1}{x_{11}} x_{22} f_{2121}(x_{11}, x_{21}, y_{11}, y_{21}).
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{4} x_{11} y_{21} = f_{1121}(x_{11}, x_{21}, y_{11}, y_{21}).
\end{align}

Here $f_{1111}, f_{2111}, f_{1121}, f_{2121}$ are functions in $x_{11}, x_{21}, y_{11}, y_{21}$.

Are there some software which can solve this system of equations exactly? Thank you very much.

Comment: make some repeated termsa as another functions, if you wish for better readability or understanding of anyone who looks this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution of this system of equations is
\begin{align}
f_{1111} & = - \frac{1}{4}x_{11} y_{11}, \\
f_{1121} & = \frac{1}{4} x_{11} y_{21}, \\
f_{2111} & = - \frac{1}{4} x_{21} y_{11}, \\
f_{2121} & = \frac{1}{4} x_{21} y_{21}.
\end{align}